# How to remember user data after disposing a jFrame?

Tags: java

Im creating basic login GUI that allows you to create an account first.  Once you create it, you can use the username and password created and Login. I also have a logOut button that goes back to the login screen. However, when I want to log back in, my credentials the username and password aren't saved and I have sign up again.(which makes no sense). How would I be able to remember the username and password after disposing the login frame.

Login Code:

```
private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String uName =txtfUserName.getText();
   String pass = passfPassword.getText();
   
    String signName = txtfSetUpUName.getText();
    String signPass = txtfSetUpPass.getText();
    
   if(uName.equals(signName) && pass.equals(signPass)){
       lblOutputMsg.setText("Access Granted");
        OptionsMenuFrame secondFrame = new OptionsMenuFrame();
        secondFrame.show();
        dispose();
       
      
       
   }else if(!uName.equals(signName) && !pass.equals(signPass)){
       lblOutputMsg.setText("Invalid Password/Username");
     
   } 
}
```

Is there any way to store the data entered by a user and return it back?

EDIT:

Login Code:

```
  private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String uName = txtfUserName.getText();
   String pass = passfPassword.getText();
   
    String signName = txtfSetUpUName.getText();
    String signPass = txtfSetUpPass.getText();
    
   if(uName.equals(signName) && pass.equals(signPass)){
       lblOutputMsg.setText("Access Granted");
        OptionsMenuFrame secondFrame = new OptionsMenuFrame();
        secondFrame.show();
        //dispose(); using setVisible instead of DISPOSE
        MainFrame firstFrame = new MainFrame();
        firstFrame.setVisible(false);
      
       
   }else if(!uName.equals(signName) && !pass.equals(signPass)){
       lblOutputMsg.setText("Invalid Password/Username");
     
   } 
}
```

LogOut Code:

```
private void btnLogOutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     dispose();
     MainFrame firstFrame = new MainFrame();
     firstFrame.setVisible(true);
     
}
```

The Code behind the login button and logout button are not linked with each other and on two separate jFrames.  Is it still possible to refer back to the original login screen without opening a brand new one?

Comment: Have you thought about using a database (MySQL, for example) to store usernames and passwords of registered users?

Comment: What does "after" mean? Do you need to remember between runs of the program, or just after you destroy the frame (so that you can use it in some other part of the program)? In the latter case, did you consider... assigning the values to variables?

Comment: _Is there any way to store the data entered by a user and return it back?_ Save it to a file?

Comment: You can use `global variables` or `static strings` but this will erase the data when the application close, if you want to store it permanently you can use any database

Answer (score 2):

In order to store user credentials permanently, you should use a database. MySQL is usually a good start. In the file where user creates an account, have an action listener hooked up to the "Create account" button:

```
create.addActionListener(new ActionListener()    {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // get entered userName
            // get entered password
            // information successfully added to user database
             if(DatabaseManager.insertInUserDatabase(userName, password))
             {
                // navigate to logged screen
             }
        }           
    });
```

The function in the DatabaseManager class that inserts user credentials into the database should look something like this:

```
public static boolean insertInUserDatabase(String username, String password)
{
    boolean added = false;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        //defining database driver to use
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/UserDatabase", "root", "");
        
        PreparedStatement oPrStmt = con
                .prepareStatement("insert into  User (username,password)  
                 values(?,?)");
                                                                                        
        oPrStmt.setString(1, username);// parameter index start from 1
        oPrStmt.setString(2, password);
        i = oPrStmt.executeUpdate(); // executing the query and getting the 
           resultset from databse
        if(i == 1)
            added = true;
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return added;
}
```

Then, next time you start your application OR log out, you can log in with the credentials that you've previously created without the need to register again:

```
logIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
        // get entered username
        // get entered password
        // if log in validation is successful
        if(DatabaseManager.validateLogIn(username, password))
        {
             // navigate to logged screen
        }
        else   // log in validation failed
        {
               // display error message
        }       
       }
    });
```

ValidateLogIn method in DatabaseManager class should look something like this:

```
public static boolean validateLogIn(String name, String pass) {
    boolean validLogin = false;
    try {
        //defining database driver to use
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/UserDatabase", "root", "");
        
        PreparedStatement oPrStmt = con
                .prepareStatement("select * from User where username=? and  
                 password=?");                                                                                          
        oPrStmt.setString(1, name);// parameter index start from 1
        oPrStmt.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs = oPrStmt.executeQuery();
            
        if (rs.next()) { //checking if the resultset has any value?   
            validLogin = true;
        }
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return validLogin;
}
```

Hope this helps! Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Geat answer. The question by OP is very broad, but I think OP has two questions, 1) How to stay registered (which you answer nicely), and 2) How how to select an existing username to autofill the username and password box, can you offer any suggestion on how that might work?

Comment: Is there any way that I could simply hide the login screen rather than completely destroying it (dispose)?  That way the Jframe is never closed but only hidden so that the credentials are remembered for later use.

Comment: You can use screen.setVisible(false) method to hide the screen and screen.setVisible(true) method to show it again. If you don't want to use a database, you can also save credentials in static (global) variables, but those values will be gone when you close your app (this is not the case with the database option - credentials inserted into the database will be stored permanently and can be used each time to run the application).

Comment: The set visible method puts the frame behind the new Jframe.  So when I go to press log out it opens up the login screen without any credentials saved but I also have the original login screen that was hidden(which has everything saved).  Is there any way I could open the original frame only rather than a brand new login screen.

Comment: It is hard to say what is going on without actually looking at your code. Judging by what you are saying, I suspect that when you click the logout button you may be creating and showing a new login screen (which you should not do). Rather, you should be referencing the original login screen by its name and calling the setVisible(true) method on that original screen.

Comment: Thank You for your help, it seems that I have got what I needed.  Instead of asking the logout button to show a brand new login screen again, I disposed the secondFrame (only).  That way it would automatically return back to the login screen that was previously hidden.  Anyhow, appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem! And just an advise, if you're interested in GUI you should ditch Swing - nobody uses it for anything - and learn a JavaScript framework like React or Angular.